# How can i solve Statement failed problem?

Tags: ubuntu, firebird

I am trying to connect FDB file on Ubuntu.

```
ubuntu@me:/opt/firebird/bin$ sudo ./isql
Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database
No entry for terminal type "xterm-256color";
using dumb terminal settings.
SQL>  connect "00.000.000.000:3050:/home/ubuntu/Firebird4.0/firebird.fdb " user 'SYSDBA' 
password 'masterkey';
```

However, i got this error:

`Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 08001 unavailable database` 
What is the problem here? How can I manage this problem?

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it invalidated the answer you received. You could ask the revised question separately, if the issue still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of IP addresses, **0.0.0.0** is a source address only.  You can not route or connect to it.

> 0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP address. RFC1700 (a) states that 0.0.0.0/8 (0.anything.anything.anything) is reserved as a source address only.
>
> Normally you'll see systems and applications bind ports to 0.0.0.0 which means the port is accessible from any interface.

From [How to communicate with a device that has an assigned “0.0.0.0”](https://superuser.com/questions/1368916/how-to-communicate-with-a-device-that-has-an-assigned-0-0-0-0-ip-address)

So, try using the server name or the IP address it is sitting at.